# Simple Asynchronous TCP Chat Application [C#]

Tags: c#, tcp

Ok, I studied a bit on asynchronous TCP network connection. I tried making one but failed. What I want to do is make sure the server or client is always ready to receive a chat and is able to send a chat any time. I do not want them to be on alternate mode.

e.g. Server Send while client waits to receive thus client can't send at that time.
I do not want that!

Did this on Windows Application. Once I connected, the system resource just shot to 100% =/

Server Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace AsyncServerChat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Socket g_server_conn;
        private byte[] g_bmsg;
        private bool check = false;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPEndPoint local_ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

            Socket winsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            winsock.Bind(local_ep);

            winsock.Listen(5);

            winsock.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Accept), winsock);
        }

        private void Accept(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket server_conn =(Socket) iar.AsyncState;

            g_server_conn = server_conn.EndAccept(iar);

            //label1.Text = "Connected. . .";

            while (g_server_conn.Connected && check == false)
            {
                g_bmsg = new byte[1024];
                check = true;
                g_server_conn.BeginReceive(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Recieve), g_server_conn);
            }
        }

        private void Send(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket server_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

            server_conn.EndSend(iar);
        }

        private void Recieve(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket server_conn =(Socket) iar.AsyncState;

            server_conn.EndReceive(iar);

            if (g_bmsg.Length != 0)
            {
                label1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length);
                check = false;
            }
        }

        private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strmsg = textBox1.Text;
            byte[] bmsg= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strmsg);

            g_server_conn.BeginSend(bmsg, 0, bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Send), g_server_conn);
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace AsyncClientChat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Socket g_client_conn;
        byte[] g_bmsg;
        private bool check = false;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPEndPoint remote_ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), 9050);

            g_client_conn = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            g_client_conn.BeginConnect(remote_ep, new AsyncCallback(Connect), g_client_conn);
        }

        private void Connect(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket client_conn =(Socket) iar.AsyncState;

            client_conn.EndConnect(iar);

            while (g_client_conn.Connected)
            {
                g_bmsg = new byte[1024];
                check = true;
                g_client_conn.BeginReceive(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Recieve), g_client_conn);
            }
        }

        private void Send(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket client_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

            client_conn.EndSend(iar);
        }

        private void Recieve(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket client_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

            client_conn.EndReceive(iar);

            if (g_bmsg.Length != 0)
            {
                label1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length);
                check = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is the `while` loop in client method `Connect`.
Remove it because it loops infinitely raising CPU usage to 100% and it's useless.

BTW, you have another problems in your code:

- **CrossThread operation exception**

For example in your `Client.Recieve` method you do:
 `label1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length);`
Actually, you're trying to set the label text from another thread (the one listening for received msgs) and this is not allowed;
Do something like this:

Create a Setter method for the label text:

```
private void SetLabelText(string txt)
{
    if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { SetLabelText1(txt); }));
    else
        label1.Text = txt;
}
```

then use the setter instead of directly call `label1.Text = ...`:

```
SetLabelText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length));
```

---

**EDIT to answer to OP comment:**

For a good and extensive explanation of what is a thread, look at its [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29).

Anyway, in simple words, a running process contains one or more threads and these are part of code that can be executed concurrently.

Starting from your TCP example, using `Socket.Receive` instead of `Socket.BeginReceive` you would have blocked the execution on `Socket.Receive()` call (I mean the lines of code after the one containing `Receive` method wouldn't be reached) until something is received.

This because `Socket.Receive` method runs on the same thread of the following code, and on each thread, the code is executed sequentially (i.e. line by line).

Conversely, using `Socket.BeginReceive`, behind the scene a new thread is created. This thread likely calls and stops on `Socket.Receive` method, and once received something it calls the method passed as parameter.

This makes `Socket.BeginReceive` asynchronous, while `Socket.Receive` is synchronous, and this is why I knew ther was another thread (when you hear asynchronous word, is extremely probable that you are dealing with multi-threading)

Thus, when you change `label.Text` you are actually setting it from another thread: the one created by `Socket.BeginReceive`.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at this code and I would start with the following suggestion.

Remove the looping from your `Accept` callback, just initiate the `BeginReceive` and let it be. Then in your `Receive` method, you can just initiate the next `BeginReceive`. This would apply for both the client and the server code, except of course for the client code you will remove the loop from your `Connect` callback method.

Then you should also watch out updating the UI controls from the callback methods, since the callback runs on the non-UI thread which can cause a host of problems. You should look at using `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke` to marshal a request back to the UI thread which can then update the controls.